# How to create a step by step wizard in C++ (with unmanaged code) in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unmanaged, wizard

I would like to build a small wizard in C++ with no dependencies on any framework.

Apparently, is really simple, but I don't know where to start. Can you point me to good information (tutorials, etc) on it. Should I use MFC Application or a Win32 project?  Is there any step by step guide ?

I'm using VS 2010. The majority of info I'd found on MFC is really old. It seems like the vast majority of development is going .net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up Property Sheets in MFC http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfs4wk4e%28VS.80%29.aspx